# Installing hybrid drive in mid-2010 17-inch MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I'm looking to expand my internal 500 GB 7200 RPM HDD that came with my 17" MacBook Pro (mid-2010) running OS X Lion.

I'm interested to hear from other MacBook Pro owners who've upgraded their HDD with hybrid (SSD + hard disk) drives, especially if they're using the Seagate Momentus XT 750 GB 7200RPM SATA 6Gb/s 32 MB Cache 2.5" Solid State Hybrid Drive ST750LX003.

Comment: I literally just finished doing this to my 2011 i7 MBP.  Seagate Momentus XT 750 and I also upgraded to 16 GB RAM. Will have to wait and see how performance looks - Geekbench scores haven't really changed after upgrade.

Comment: Hi Jason, I'll really appreciate if you could share your experience after some time using it. Does it generate noticeable heat? Drain battery life more than usual? Did you have to disable the Sudden Motion Sensor using pmset? Thanks very much.

Comment: after using the MBP for a full work day after upgrading, it seems very stable.  Performance is good - not earth shattering - but switching between OS X and W7 running VS2010 (under VMWare Fusion) is much smoother than before.  No beach balls.  No noticeable change in noise or vibration from the new drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a late 2011 15" 2.2 quad core i7 macbook pro, and after using it with a 7200 rpm hard drive for about 2 months I decided to upgrade it to the Seagate Momentus XT 500GB Hybrid drive. I am a iOS programmer and I can't tell you what a big difference this hard drive made in my computer. I did a couple of tests before I changed out my old hard drive like boot up time and opening programs and such. With my 7200 RPM hard drive my boot up time was 31 sec. and with the hybrid drive my new boot up time is 20 sec. I strongly recommend the hybrid drives. Seagate also just updated there hybrid drives with twice the amount of solid state memory instead of 4 GB they now have 8 GB. I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks very much for sharing. Now I'm more confident of getting one too :)